# How to get the function of a eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I can use `getEventListeners(myElem)` to get the list of events, but how can I get the function of these events?

Example:

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");

var myFunction = (el) => {
  console.log(el);
}

myDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", myFunction);

//getEventListeners(myDiv)./* pathToFunction */.myFunction("test");
//expected log: "test"
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">This is my element, click it!</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is asked because the actual code doesn't know that the function is `myFunction`?  I'm confused by the need for this.

Comment: in chrome you can write: window.getEventListeners(document.querySelector("#myDiv")).mousedown[0].listener

Comment: yeah, the code doesnt know what `myFunction` is, this was just a exemple.

Comment: @gaetanoM, but this doesnt return the real function, i want to get the location of it in the source code on the developers tool

Comment: @LuísHNrique I assume it is not possible. Consider getEventListeners is available only in chrome.....

Comment: @gaetanoM, this really works, i just tryed [IMAGE](https://i.ibb.co/RpV9Nwf/image.png), but for some reason, the element im trying to execute this doesnt show the function or the path to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works only in Chrome:

```
window.getEventListeners(document.querySelector("#myDiv")).mousedown[0].listener
```